# An example for using SharpArch with c# windows applications?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, desktop-application, windows, sharp-architecture

Are there any example for using S#arp Architecture with c# desktop windows applications, i notices that SharpArch.Contrib provide some functionality to do that but i need some example>

Comment: S#arp Architecture is framework for *WEB* applications. Parts of it can be used for Windows apps too, but the question doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How to use Sharp Architecture and Contrib in Windows GUI and service applications](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture-Contrib/wiki/How-to-use-Sharp-Architecture-and-Contrib-in-Windows-GUI-and-service-applications)